# NSManagedObjectContext - Which of these 2 methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Would you modify a view controllers initializer to get the NSManagedObjectContext from the appdelegate?

or would you use this method?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use the line that you provided and it works perfectly fine.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

One thing I have found in all of my Cocoa development is that there are many ways to skin a cat.  Usually what works best for you is the best way to go about it.

Another way you could do it is to add the NSManagedObjectContext to the NIB and then add outlets to it in all of your other controllers that need a reference to it.  That would require a bit of modification to your App Delegate though.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it would be the one you wrote. But I rather want to find out the pros and cons about different methods :) Yeah I could do it with IB, that is a third method :P But that isn't suited for me. I rather do my UI programmatically. :)